# Creating an intranet site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

How would I set up my database to enable it to be accessed from other computers on my network. I want to create a local website and/or application for my home computers that uses this database.

1. How would I set up the database to be accessed over a home network?
2. How can I create a local website which allows anyone on the network to connect to?

Is it necessary when creating a local website, you'd need to enable world wide services firewall exception(already done)? How can an intranet user address this website?

I'm using SQL Server and ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to approach it like this:

- install IIS on a machine on the intranet. This will be your intranet web server. Let's assume it's named `machine1`. Usually you won't need to make a Windows Firewall exception, as the install/config will do this for you. Make sure it's up and running: `http://machine1`
- have SQL Server installed on a machine on the intranet. It could be the same as your web server, perhaps not. Let's call this `machine2`.
- develop your ASP.NET application. If you choose the default ASP.NET Webforms template, you'll be using Forms Authentication, and you won't need to worry about security at this point.
- your ASP.NET site will have a web.config connection string like

`Data Source=machine2;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`

- deploy/publish the app to the default IIS directory on that server (c:\inetpub\wwwroot). This can be configured later if you like.
- intranet users can browse to `http://machine1`

This isn't meant to be an exhaustive list, and you may run into a snag or two, depending on your environment.

Answer (score 2):

You enable network access for your SQL Server instance via [Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165718.aspx).

That will allow your website to connect to it.  You don't need a WWW firewall exception to access the DB (and in fact, should try and restrict access to it as much as possible), it has a server port is 1433, and client ports are assigned a random value between 1024 and 5000.

For the website, you'll need to enable HTTP and possibly HTTPS, and of coure add firewall rules appropriately for those.  If another user inside your home network wants to connect, they can use the computer name if you have WINS or DNS working, or if they add the name & IP to their local etc/hosts file; they can't use the name if neither are working and there's no hosts entry.